# Django Test Client Redirects Unexpectedly

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing

Currently, I am using TestCase to make a HTTP Post request which is being redirected and does not have the post data.  I'd like to make a post request without it being redirected and to preserve the data.  How do I do so?

1) Evidence of redirection:

babies/urls.py
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('babies',
  # Endpoints
  url(r'^create_baby/$', 'views.create_baby'),
  ...
)
```

babies/tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
import pdb
class OrderCreationTest(TestCase): 
  def setUp(self):
    self.normal_baby_data = {
      'birth_time': {
        'date' : '04-07-2013'
      }
    } 
  def test_baby_creation(self):
    response = self.client.post('/consumer/create_baby/', 
                            self.normal_baby_data,
                            follow=True
                            )
    pdb.set_trace()
```

bash results:

```
(Pdb) response.redirect_chain
[('https://testserver/consumer/create_baby/', 302)]
```

If follow=False then the view's create_baby method is never created and also there is not redirect chain. The bash results are:

```
(Pdb) response.redirect_chain
*** AttributeError: 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'redirect_chain'
```

2) Evidence that there is no post data

babies/views.py

```
def create_baby(request):
  pdb.set_trace()
  ...

(Pdb) p request
<WSGIRequest
path:/consumer/create_baby/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'sessionid': 'f88ffoplh6lyytarn9n85z6bd5lefbzo'},
META:{u'CONTENT_TYPE': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
 u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'OC5LFOj8HvqTu0cKoAmty7vkYP0jNk3Q',
 u'HTTP_COOKIE': u' sessionid=f88ffoplh6lyytarn9n85z6bd5lefbzo; Domain=None; expires=None; Max-Age=None; Path=/; secure',
 u'PATH_INFO': u'/consumer/create_order/',
 u'QUERY_STRING': '',
 u'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 u'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 u'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 u'SERVER_NAME': 'testserver',
 u'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 u'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 u'wsgi.errors': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x10a6fa230>,
 u'wsgi.input': <django.test.client.FakePayload object at 0x10b067b50>,
 u'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 u'wsgi.multithread': False,
 u'wsgi.run_once': False,
 u'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your own pdb dump,

```
<WSGIRequest path:/consumer/create_order/, ...>
```

Somewhere, the request is being rerouted to push you to `/consumer/create_order/`

- Check your urls.py to make sure everything's wired up properly
- Check your middleware to make sure it's not sending back redirects
- Check your create_baby() view to make sure there are no logic errors.

If this is actually the intended behavior, you need to know that POST data **does not** survive redirects. This is a feature of the browser, not a bug in Django.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for the quick response.  I was changing the variable names before posting to stackoverflow.  <WSGIRequest path:/consumer/create_order/, ...> actually is supposed to be <WSGIRequest path:/consumer/create_baby/, ...>.  Also, I understand that POST data does not survive redirects so right now I'm trying to figure out why there is a redirect in the firs place.

Comment: perhaps you should put a trace point in `django.shortcuts.redirect`

Answer (score 2):

**(OK, nothing to do with the OP's issue, but quite relevant to a Django test client 302)**

FWIW, if you have login/auth in place for a view, check that your client_stub login is successful.  I would have expected an exception from:

```
res = cls.client_stub.login(username=cls.username, password=cls.password)
```

It wasn't complaining at all, but in fact, my username and password were not set and the login was failing.  The actual url being tested further was getting the 302 to the login page resulting from that failed login.